# How to post a href value via jquery ajax when the page has more than 200 values?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code repeated over and over again in a page where all that changes is the id_filme value.

```
<a href="import/add-filmespessoa.php?id_pessoa=2&id_filme=658" class="add2"><img src="img/icone-plus1.png" width="16px" alt=""></a>
<a href="import/add-filmespessoa.php?id_pessoa=3&id_filme=658" class="add3"><img src="img/icone-plus2.png" width="16px" alt=""></a>
```

And I wanted this HREF to be loaded using AJAX and jQuery and then change the image icone-plus1.png or icone-plus2.png (would depend on each one was clicked) to icon-plus-success.png.

So far I have this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.add2').click(function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url2 = $(".add2").attr("href");
            alert(url2);
    $.get(url2);
});
$('a.add3').click(function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url3 = $(".add3").attr("href");
    $.get(url3);
}); 
});
</script>
```

The problem is the url is not picked up correctly (uses always the one picked from the first time that code appears on a page) and I have no idea how can I change the image after it is clicked.

This seems pretty basic ... but just not to my level of knowledge with jQuery ... can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.add2').click(function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url2 = $(this).attr("href");
            alert(url2);
    $.get(url2);
});
$('a.add3').click(function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url3 = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url3);
}); 
});
</script>
```

Note the only change I had to make was changing your call to .attr("href") from looking at the whole class (either .add2 or .add3) to instead refer to the attr of the currently-clicked object (this).

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.7+ then you probably want to be using `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: If you want to change image then do this. `$(this).children('img').prop('src', newimageurl);` This gets the child image of the clicked item and changes its src file. http://jsfiddle.net/H47cu/

Comment: DANG!!!! I was that close huh!!!! Almost made my first snippet of jQuery all by myself without copy&pasting :D Thanks @Jake Feasel, spared me a lot of time

Comment: Thanks also @mrtsherman ! Your line of code worked like a charm!